# C# properties FileSystem

Tags: c#, asp.net, filesystems

```
 DirectoryInfo directory;
 public string Name {
            get { return this.directory.Name; }
            set { this.directory.Name = value; }
        }
```

Hi. I have this code in c# . It doesn't work I get this error:

> *Property or Indexer System.Io.FileSystemInfo.Name cannot be assigned
>   to -- it's read only.*

What can I do ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `DirectoryInfo` does exactly what it says it does - gets you info on a directory. Are you trying to change the directory that it's pointing to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three possibilities:

- Remove the setter entirely, making it a read-only property
- Change the value of `directory` to refer to the specified directory
- (Bizarre and dangerous!) Rename the directory on the file system so that its name is now as specified

Without knowing what your property is really meant to represent, it's hard to really say which of these options is appropriate, if any.

Answer (score 1):

Just as the compiler says, `DirectoryInfo`'s inherited `Name` property is read-only.  The expression `this.directory.Name = value;` is erroneous; you cannot assign to a read-only property.

To make your class' `Name` property read-only, just remove the setter altogether.  If you want the property to be writable, then you need to figure out what it means to write to your `Name` property and carry out whatever logic is necessary to transform the object's state appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

`DirectoryInfo.Name` is read-only, you cannot modify it. You should remove it from your code. However, if you'd like to change a directory's name, you would write something like this:

```
System.IO.Directory.Move("oldDirName", "newDirName");
```